# Google Spreadsheet arrayformula between day and hours

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'm struggling with a formula where I have to calculate whether a person's absence time is hours or days. The normal formula works but when I change it to ARRAY it doesn't work anymore

| data1 | Data 2 | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 08:00:00 | 01/01/2021 09:10:00 | only hour |
| 04/01/2021 08:00:00 | 09/01/2021 08:00:00 | days |

**normal formula:**

```
=IF(IF(AND(DAY(D2)=DAY(E2);MONTH(D2)=MONTH(E2));1;0)=1;(HOUR(E2)-HOUR(D2))/10;DATEDIF(D2;E2;"d"))
```

**array formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(IF(AND(DAY(D2:D)=DAY(E2:E);MONTH(D2:D)=MONTH(E2:E));1;0)=1;(HOUR(E2:E)-HOUR(D2:E))/10;DATEDIF(D2:D;E2:E;"D")))
```

**example link**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EFxugOajxOAEDUgJQEalOXVpKrFwEm2YWSK_N2hq4gw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `AND(condition1; condition2)` and `OR(condition1; condition2)` do not work in `ARRAYFORMULA` and should be replaced with `(condition1) * (condition2)` and `(condition1) + (condition2)` (parenthesis are required) accordingly. Also, why there is a division by 10? Why not just use `DATEDIF(...; "d") > 0` as a single condition?